# How can I access the container of an element in Applescript?

Tags: applescript

I want to do something like the following:

```
container of (1st static text of rows of tables of ¬
  scroll areas of (1st window whose title contains ¬
  "motorola") whose value contains "16225")
--> row N of table N of scroll area N of …
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `value of attribute "AXParent"`. `attributes of` shows other attributes of UI elements.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Finder"
    value of attribute "AXParent" of some UI element of window 1
end
```